# Schengen eligibility following a removal and visa cancellation

Tags: visas, schengen, italy, removal, proof-of-accommodation

I have a Schengen multiple entry visa. Last week I travelled to Rome, Italy but I forgot to reserve a hotel. They ask me about a hotel or invitation letter; I didn't have either but I showed him my cash money, yet they denied me entry in Rome. Then I'm back in Qatar then I ask with consulate then they told me your visa is cancelled. Now I want to know can I apply new Schengen visa soon? Italy or other country? My nationality in Indian

Comment: Your question is quite unstructured. If the Italian Embassy told you that your visa was cancelled, you can't use it any more. Normally, you will also have a stamp in your passport documenting this. You can of course apply for a new visa, but note that your previous inability to meet the admission requirements will be held against you.

Comment: On a related note: if you were unable show any proof of an accommodation reservation, then how did you expect to find it in Rome? (A PDF on your cell phone may have already been sufficient). I just feel that your question is incomplete as it is now, so you may not get the right answers.

Comment: Was the visa "revoked" or "annulled"? It would be a bit odd not to do it on the spot at the border but in any case, you should have gotten a form spelling this out and citing one of the standard reasons to cancel a visa. What's on that form?

Comment: I am curious how you got the visa in the first place without a hotel reservation.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid Might have cancelled the reservation after getting the visa.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid also second and subsequent entries can be made without going ti embassy, thus no hotel reservation..

Answer (score 11):

As I understand it, you were issued a Schengen and travelled to Italy.  During your landing interview you were challenged for proof of accommodation and you could not provide it, instead you said you had forgotten to make reservations.  You were then removed to your original departure destination.  In a subsequent enquiry at the issuing post you were informed that your visa had been cancelled.

If I understand your narrative correctly, then the obvious starting point is your forgetting to make accommodation arrangements.  Forgetfulness of this magnitude is an indicator that points to several possibilities:

- That you may not be a genuine traveller; or
- More alarmingly, that you expect to die before needing accommodation; or
- That your situational awareness is unstable to the extent that you
  may forget other aspects of your visit like observing the terms and
  conditions of your visa; or
- That your visa may be a forgery.

The border officials do not need hard facts, they are entitled to act on indications and hence you were removed.  As part of the process, they gave you some paperwork that has your reference number and summary of the grounds for your removal. Hang on to it, you will need it later.

Your questions...

> Now I want to know can I apply new Schengen visa soon ?

The terms of your removal, if any, will be spelled out in your paperwork, but overall there is no mandatory cooling off period following a Schengen removal. My personal view on it is that you were not in breach and hence this was not a grave incident warranting a ban.  On the other hand, these things have a huge effect on whether subsequent applications will be successful.  It's likely that the Schengen officials will not trust you for a while which casts an unfavourable outlook on your suitability, but nothing you wrote about prevents you from applying again.  Check your paperwork.

> Italy or other country ?

The procedures governing which consulate is appropriate for making an application have not changed, you can apply to any country where your agenda meets the rules (first country, most time, and so on).  This includes Italy.  Note that they have computer systems in place to record removals and to help detect 'visa shopping'.

If you have lost your paperwork (or don't remember getting it) or have lots of questions about your suitability, you should arrange a consultation with a [lawyer that specialises in Schengen removals](http://communities.lawsociety.org.uk/international/regions/europe/italy/).